# Open conversation in Whatsapp and populate the text

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to open `WhatsApp` to a specific conversation and populate the text field with some string.

Code that I have and I managed to open the conversation with a contact:

```
private void openConversationWithWhatsapp(String e164PhoneNumber){
    String whatsappId = e164PhoneNumber+"@s.whatsapp.net";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + whatsappId);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email");
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "The text goes here");
    intent.putExtra("text","asd");
    intent.putExtra("body","body");
    intent.putExtra("subject","subjhect");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The text box however is not filled with content. I tried to peek inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and found the following info regarding their conversation activity:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.App.CondensedActionBar" android:name="com.whatsapp.Conversation" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Does somebody know the extra to use?
Are they blocking this on purpose?
I saw an API for iOS that they have in their [FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013) page.

Comment: However Whatsapp does not have an open API. The code you use is not guaranteed to work forever!

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-whatsapp

Answer (score 10):

Update in 2017

based on this [Whatsapp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251)

im using this url

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62xxxxxxx&text=Hello,%20from%20my%20Apps
```

which 62 is Indonesia's Dialing code

then i use intent like this (im using kotlin)

```
val uri = Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62xxxxxxx&text=Hello,%20from%20my%20Apps")
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        startActivity(intent)
```

replace 62xxxxx with your number
this work fine to me

Comment: You must specify a country dialing code for this intent to work. Otherwise whatsapp will present an error-message

Answer (score 9):

**Sadly, they didn't implement this feature on android** (maybe they do in the future).

I already asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-whatsapp), but with no results. While whatsapp reacts to some intents like the one you show in your code, they simply don't use the text you send. I suppose this is because of safety reasons, imagine the amount of whatsapp-spammer apps in the play store... I don't know how (and why) it is implemented in iOS...

The **two alternatives** that come close to your solution are

1. send the text and [create a chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931345/2829009) (no need to type, just select whatsapp)
2. [open the contact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16298936/2829009) (text needs to be typed, but no need to select the contact)

Comment: rightly said. Its for safety reasons. But the new update of Google Now sends direct whatsApp message to specific contact. How could they do it? Is there a new API opened up in whatsApp or something else?

Comment: Google Now partnered with 3rd parties messaging to get it work. There isn't an API by whatsapp for sure.

Comment: This answer is outdate, @Ekky Hermestian IW has the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47635819/2614353

Answer (score 8):

I have done it!

```
private void openWhatsApp() {
    String smsNumber = "7****"; //without '+'
    try {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        //sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: is this still pressing the SEND button / mimicing the ENTER key? @Alexey

Comment: what is the "jid" part when setting the phone number?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following solution to send image and text.

You can setType as "text" and remove extra_stream to use it only for sending text.

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            File f=new File("path to the file");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.ContactPicker"));
            sendIntent.setType("image");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("919xxxxxxxxx")+"@s.whatsapp.net");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"sample text you want to send along with the image");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

**EXTRA INFORMATION ABOUT THE PROCESS OF FINDING THE SOLUTION :**

After reverse engineering WhatsApp, I came across the following snippet of Android manifest,

Normal Share intent, uses "**SEND**" which does not allow you to send to a  specific contact and requires a contact picker.

The specific contact is picked up by Conversation class and uses "**SEND_TO**" action, but it uses sms body and can not take up image and other attachments.

```
 <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:name="com.whatsapp.Conversation" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.CondensedActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="sms"/>
                <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Digging further, I came across this,

```
 <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:name="com.whatsapp.ContactPicker" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="com.whatsapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/msword"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="send" android:scheme="whatsapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service" android:value=".ContactChooserTargetService"/>
        </activity>
```

Finally using a decompiler for ContactPicker and Conversation class,the extra key-value for phone number was found to be "**jid**".

Comment: Do you know how to send preffilled message to Conversation class ? what is the key value pair for that

Answer (score 2):

Use Below code to Open conversations in what's App

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%s", "91xxxxxxxxxx")));
            if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please install whatsApp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Note : always enter the country code without "+" to the number.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1 - Using android component name**

```
 public static void openWhatsAppConversation(Context context, String number, String message) {

    number = number.replace(" ", "").replace("+", "");

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(number) + "@s.whatsapp.net");

    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

**Method 2 - Using whatsapp api uri**

```
public static void openWhatsAppConversationUsingUri(Context context, String numberWithCountryCode, String message) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + numberWithCountryCode + "&text=" + message);

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void sendMessageOnWhatsApp(String number, String text, Context context){
    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number+"&text="+text;
    Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
    whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    whatsappIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        context.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toaster.showMessageShort(context.getString(R.string.no_whatsapp_msg));
    }

}
```

Comment: works for sending whats app message to an o which is not in contact list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet for WhatsApp:

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }  
}
```

Comment: It looks like that PackageInfo is not used on this snippet. Why it is required?

Comment: It is a copied answer! `PackageInfo` was used to check if whatsapp is installed or not. It returns `null` if whatsapp is not installed. Later, this got removed from that answer based on some comments. So, the answering guy put code of `else` block in `catch` block.

Comment: @ChristianSisti: The line is used to check if WhatsApp is installed or not. If it isn't installed, getPackageInfo() throws an exception and the catch block gets executed. Review https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html for documentation on how getPackageInfo() works.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me . where the **jid** is the phone number without '+' 
and this supports **MODIFIED** Versions of **WhatsApp** like WhatsApp+ etc.. 
only by passing the **WhatsApp Package Name** .
you can find full Code in [MyApp](https://github.com/3llomi/QuickWhatsAppMessage)

```
   private void openChat(String text, String packageName) {
        if (text.trim().isEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            try {
                String smsNumber = Util.getNumber(text) + "@s.whatsapp.net";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + smsNumber);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                i.putExtra("jid", smsNumber);
                i.setPackage(packageName);
                context.startActivity(i);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Make Sure you have WhatsApp App Installed on Your Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
            Intent whatappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            whatappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            whatappIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            whatappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            if (whatappIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
               startActivity(whatappIntent);
            } else {
                Log.d("msg","WhatsApp Not installed")
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer