# automatically send a whatsapp message to a contact without user involvement

Tags: android, android-studio, whatsapp

hi am an android developer
my requirement is to send a whatsapp message to particular mobile number pro-grammatically without user involvement (that is like google voice where we can send message to particular contact by voice command), i have tried many ways but only able to open whatsapp app and put the message which i want send, but facing problem in sending pro-grammatically to that contact
kindly give suggestions 
this is what i tried
[How can I open WhatsApp's conversation activity using contact data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121163/how-can-i-open-whatsapps-conversation-activity-using-contact-data/16298936#16298936)
thanks in advance

Comment: Check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40285262/5879376

Comment: @RishabhMaurya, it will open whats app conversation screen only, you can even set message to it. You have to type it manually :)

Comment: It is the best option so far. You can't expect option like Google assistant .

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
 myIntent.setComponent(new  ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
 myIntent.putExtra("abc", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("PHONE_NUMBER")+"@s.whatsapp.net");
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Where PHONE_NUMBER is number of the contact to which you want to send the message.

Comment: is the button is pressed by this code automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto" + "12345");
                    Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);
                    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    startActivity(i);
```